# Parsing json with android

Tags: android, json

Hi I want to parse this json:

```
[{
    "codError": 0,
    "msg": "OK"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "role": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Super",
        "description": "Roling.",
        "rights": [],
        "superuser": true,
        "active": true,
        "optimisticLock": 0
    },
    "now": null,
    "points": [],
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "loginName": "admin",
    "password": null,
    "connected": true,
    "active": true,
    "optimisticLock": null
},
["U4"]
]
```

I want to get **role id** that is ***4***, the **loginName** that is ***admin*** and the value of the array **U4**.

Here is how I am trying to do the parse:

```
     // Role node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject role = getJSONObject(TAG_ROLE);
                    String role_id = role.getInt(TAG_ROLE_ID);
                    String loginName = getJSONObject(TAG_LOGINNAME);
```

how can I get U4 value? Thank you very much

Comment: Your JSON response format is not as per standard.

Comment: I don´t understand your answer, can you explain me more? thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

`{` represents the Jsonobject and `[` represents the jsonarray

Parse like this to get the `role_id`  `loginName` from your json

```
 JSONArray jsonarr =new  JSONArray(yourstring);
 JSONObject jobj=jsonarr.getJSONObject(1);
 JSONObject role =jobj.getJSONObject("role");
 String role_id = role.getInt("id");
 String loginName=jsonarr.getString("loginName");
```

Comment: but your `U4` key doesnot contain any value so it is not possible to parse.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the U4 doesn't seems JSON correct. I would have write it like:

```
{
  "your array":["U4"]
}
```

then use the method to get your array

```
JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("your array");
```

then you can access the values on your JSONArray by iterating over it, like that

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  array.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Hope I help

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
JSONArray arry=new JSONArray("yourjsonstring");
for(int i=0;i<arry.length();i++)
 {
      JSONObject obj=arry.getJSONObject(i);
     String role=obj.getString("role");
     JSONObject obj2=new JSONObject(role);
      String id=obj2.getString("id");
     JSONArray array =obj.getJSONArray("U4");
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but if i don´t know the value of the json Array? I can´t put in my code getJSONArray U4 because this can change to U5, U6...

Comment: @Igor In that case it will be difficult to parse your array if it will be changing. You need to work more on your response.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, I am novice parsing, now I understand your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Why should we do parsing of JSON if you are provided a ready made tool to parse a JSON and give you a complete hierarchy of Java classes???

Right??

Take a look at [JsonSchema 2 Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) site.

Provide your JSON input/output there. Select appropriate options like

> Source type: JSON
>   Annotation style: GSON

Enable following 3 options

1. Generate builder methods
2. Use primitive types
3. Use long integers

Select **Jar** button and you are done with.

### Note

Please validate your JSON first.