# Parse json array

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse this json:

```
    [{
    "codError": 0,
    "msg": "OK"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "role": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Super",
        "description": "Roling.",
        "rights": [],
        "superuser": true,
        "active": true,
        "optimisticLock": 0
    },
    "now": null,
    "points": [],
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "loginName": "admin",
    "password": null,
    "connected": true,
    "active": true,
    "optimisticLock": null
},
["U4"]

]
```

I am not able to get the value of role id and loginName, my code is here:

```
private static final String TAG_ROLE = "role";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {


                     JSONArray jsonarr =new  JSONArray(jsonStr);

                     JSONObject jobj=jsonarr.getJSONObject(1);
                     JSONObject role =jobj.getJSONObject(TAG_ROLE);
                     String role_id = role.getString(TAG_ID);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I debug my app and String role_id doesn´t get any value, what is the problem of the code? Thank you

Comment: Same question again!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405108/parsing-json-with-android

Comment: Once check TAG_ROLE and TAG_ID and then use getInt instead of getString.

Comment: yes is the same question because still not working, tag_role and Tag_id are ok

Comment: you already asked that exact question.

Comment: did you replace getString with getInt. comment me about result

Comment: yes I know, can I edit my old question, to ask again? I don´t know how it works...

Comment: if tag_id is string I have to do getString, isn´t it?

Comment: The value your are trying to get is integer.so you need to call getInt

Comment: it still not working with getInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray array;
array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(1);
JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("role");
int id = obj2.getInt("id");
String name = obj2.getString("name");
```

In case you aren't getting any values, you might want to check if the response is exactly how you're expecting it to be. Also, check the values of TAG_ROLE, TAG_ID.

Edit 1 :

```
String jsonStr = "[{\n    \"codError\": 0,\n    \"msg\": \"OK\"\n}, {\n    \"id\": 1,\n    \"role\": {\n        \"id\": 4,\n        \"name\": \"Super\",\n        \"description\": \"Roling.\",\n        \"rights\": [],\n        \"superuser\": true,\n        \"active\": true,\n        \"optimisticLock\": 0\n    },\n    \"now\": null,\n    \"points\": [],\n    \"firstName\": null,\n    \"lastName\": null,\n    \"loginName\": \"admin\",\n    \"password\": null,\n    \"connected\": true,\n    \"active\": true,\n    \"optimisticLock\": null\n},\n[\"U4\"]\n\n]";

try {
        JSONArray array;
        array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(1);
        JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("role");
        int id = obj2.getInt("id");
        String name = obj2.getString("name");
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(name);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, sorry but I have copy your code and still not working

Comment: Edited code. The problem might be with "id": 4, where 4 is an integer, not a String. Nobody noticed this in your previous question also :-)

Comment: thank you so much, now I get the id but I get 1 and it has to be 4 and also I am not get the loginName, to get the loginName it will be like this? String loginname = obj.getString("loginName");? Thank yo so so much

Comment: Edit 1 : gives me 4 as the id. 
obj.getString("loginName") will give you the loginName. 

Also, Please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: The id was correct, sorry was my issue, but can´t I get the loginName now with String login_name= obj.getString("loginName")

Comment: Works for me. Do you get any exception ?

Comment: Works right, thank you very very much, you are very helpful although I have duplicate my question, people like you make this page bigger, constructive people :-) many thanks!